# How do PUT request in Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, request

I have `titleField` and `UITextView`. How do I implement PUT request in Firebase and send data from text field to Firebase?

Comment: put your tried code

Comment: NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
  NSDictionary *post = @{@"sender": self.titleField.text,
                           @"message": self.textView.text,
                           @"time": [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:now                                                                 dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle                                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle],                           };
    NSDictionary *childUpdates = @{@"https://nasheradio-eda64.firebaseio.com/message.json": post};
    [_ref updateChildValues:childUpdates]

Comment: @LipatovEugen please add the code to your question by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43343488/edit) link under it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to put it.
if you have a simple structure, find the link of database cell.
https://YOUR_DATABASE_REF.firebaseio.com/CHILD/CHILD_OF_CHILD/

```
    FIRDatabaseReference *reference = YOUR_REF;

        NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    self.textField.text,SOME_NAME"KEY",                                                                                                                                                                                    nil];

[reference updateChildValues:values withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *__nullable err, FIRDatabaseReference * ref){
                                                                   if(err) {
                                                                       NSLog(@"Error save");
                                                                       return;
                                                                   }
                                                                   NSLog(@"Saved seccessfully in FireBace db");
                                                               }];
```